# Is there a way to change scale of y axis in python plot?

Tags: python, pandas

Currently i am able to generate this plot to calculate number of people using applications,
but i am getting y axis values as in decimals ,where in people cannot be in decimals.
how can i change this ?

```
df_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df_removed1,index=['Module'],columns=['Date'], aggfunc='size').plot(kind='bar',grid=True)
plt.xticks(weight='bold')
plt.xlabel(App_req,size="25",weight='bold')
plt.title(grph_title)
```

this is the code i am using to plot graph for my data

[current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMNEQ.png)

Comment: https://www.delftstack.com/howto/matplotlib/set-x-axis-values-matplotlib/

Answer (score 1):

You can try to give `yticks()` the integers generated by `range()`:

```
plt.yticks(range(0,2))
```

Otherwise you can try:

```
from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
plt.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using
`plt.set_yticks()`

docs here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticks.html